# How to fetch full word from string against matched pattern in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching, preg-match, preg-match-all

I want to get full word from matched pattern from string.

for example if i have string

```
$string = "Loreim ipsum lorem ipsum @Leader_abcXyz! loreim ipsum loreim ipsum @Leader_xyzAbc! loreim ipsum lorem ipsul @Leader_jklMno oremipsuim!";
$pattern = "@Leader_";
$result = someRegularExpression($string,$pattern);
```

I want result in $result as @Leader_abcXyz!,@Leader_xyzAbc! and @Leader_jklMno oremipsuim!

I want to notify user if admin mention their user name with @ in editor. so i want to fetch word after @Leader_ , so i can get that word and send them mail.

Comment: If you tagged your question with `preg_match`, why write `sumFunction` in the code? Please show the patter that does not work for you. `@Leader_` is not a valid PHP regex.

Comment: I have tried many preg_match, sumFunction was spell mistake. @Leader_ will be common pattern / identifier. i can change it . In short, i just want abcXyz, xyzAbc from @Leader_abcXyz! and @Leader_xyzAbc! respectively. Thanks for quick reply.

Comment: Please show what you tried and explain what exactly did not work.

Comment: I tried

preg_match('@^(?:Leader)?([^@]+)@i',
    "asdfasfsfsdf Leader_KevinAvard_1500975840", $matches);
$host = $matches[1];

Also tried

$szPostContent = "asdfasfsfsdf Leader_KevinAvard_1500975840 asdfasdfsdf @Leader_KevinAvard_1500975840 asdfasdfsdf Leader_KevinAvard_1500975840 asdfasdfsdf Leader_KevinAvard_1500975840 asdfasdfsdf";

preg_match("/Leader_(.*)/", $szPostContent, $results) ;
echo "<pre>";
print_r($results);

Comment: Ok, why did you try `'@^(?:Leader)?([^@]+)@i'`? There are `!` marks at the right boundary, right? Then you must have used `[^!]+`. That is let alone the fact that `@` are used as regex delimiters, so the `@` inside should be escaped. Also, you have `_` in the input, it should also be present in the pattern. Try `preg_match('~@Leader_\K[^!]+~i', $str, $matches); $host = $matches[1];`

Comment: I want to notify user if admin mention their user name with @ in editor. so i want to fetch word after @Leader_ , so i can get that word and send them mail.

Comment: sorry but i am not getting you. Can you please give me full preg match, so i can try.

Comment: See my previous comment with the `preg_match`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
@Leader_(\w+)\s*(.*?)!
```

Captures the characters after leader, and will then capture anything available until the next exclamation point.

See the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/dI6DLL/1)

Or maybe this?

```
@Leader_([\w]+)\s*(.*?)[[:punct:]]
```

Captures the characters after leader and then anything available until the next punctuation mark

See the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/dI6DLL/2)